# Using File (Field) Paths with token value from Entity Reference field

Tags: 8, tokens

I am using Drupal 8.3.1 and using the module [File (Field) Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) to define the path and filename.  I want to use the value of a taxonomy field (Entity reference in CCK) in the same content type as part of the filename.  The machine name of the field is *field_organization* and doing *[node:field_organization]* produces an href link where I want is just the name of the single value it contains.  How do I get only the term's name instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to append `:value` to the field:

```
[node:field_organization:value]
```

For a reference field something like this:

```
[node:field_organization:0:entity:name]
```

If you want to look up all available tokens install the [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module and go to */admin/help/token*.

Comment: Thank you!  Is there any way to have tokens be transformed (spaces removed for example)?  I want to avoid PathAuto as to not affect both filenames and urls.